# writing shapes and strokes in files

Tags: c#, wpf

I developing a program in `WPF` and need to write and read `shapse`(rectangle,ellipse,...) in file and read them.

is there any way for that or i must write its specification like width, height, ... an load them?
any idea?

i used from:

```
  Stream stream = File.Open("mehdi.txt", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
            a.Add(shapelist);  //shapelist is arraylist

            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, a);
            stream.Close();
```

but this code has following error:

```
Type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked!

```
 FileStream f = new FileStream("mehdi.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); // 
        XamlWriter.Save(inkcanvas, f);
        foreach (var e1 in inkcanvas.Children) // 
        XamlWriter.Save(e1);
        foreach (var e1 in inkcanvas.Strokes)
               XamlWriter.Save(e1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the XAML (Rectangle, Ellipse, etc) that describes your "designs" as separate .xaml files.

Then you can load/save that XAML on demand using `XAMLReader.Load/Save`.

This will create an object which you can then set as the Content/add wherever you would like it to show up in your UI.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115108/Lazy-Load-XAML-content-from-External-File-and-Vice
- http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/10/lazy-load-xaml-content-from-external.html

Comment: it trowed following error: Cannot serialize a generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Windows.UIElement]‌​'. on save line –

Comment: Can you show the XAML/Object tree your trying to save....and the code you are using to do the save with. Don't use ArrayList...just specify the XAML object you want to save.

Comment: this program is like paint draw rectangles ellipse and ... i wanna to save them and load like paint.
                FileStream stream = new FileStream("mehdi.txt", FileMode.Create);
                {
                    XamlWriter.Save(this.Content, stream);
                }

Comment: What do you have set as the Content...please show the XAML....or codebehind that you use to build the Content...make sure the types are serializable.

Comment: type rectangle was not seriazable how can i serialize it?if it possible?